# iphone development: nstimer calling a function

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, function, nstimer, method-call

I have a void function which just have `NSLog(@"Call me");` in its body.

I call it in my view in every ten seconds by using

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(yourMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

But I want it to stop it after 5 iterations. However it goes to infinity. How can I do that?

Comment: Create an iVar which increments every cycle and if it reaches 5: `[timer invalidate]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Keep a global variable, that increments from 0 to 5.

```
  int i = 0;
```

2) Incement this variable inside your timer function..

```
-(void) yourFunction:(NSTimer*)timer{
  //do your action

  i++;
  if(i == 5){
     [timer invalidate];
  }
}
```

3) When creating timer

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 
                 target:self 
                 selector:@selector(yourMethod:) // <== see the ':', indicates your function takes an argument 
                 userInfo:nil 
                 repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

You should take one counter, increment it every time when your method get called, count for 5 and then invalidate your timer using below code.

```
[timer invalidate];
```

Answer (score 1):

To destroy the timer from the current loop, you should call `[timer invalidate];`

To determine five occurrences, you need to maintain a variable and increment its count each time. If it is equal to 5, call invalidate method.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to declare an `int` and declare your `NSTimer *timer`, so we can stop it:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIViewController {
    int myInt;
    NSTimer *timer;
}
```

To start the `NSTimer` you'll need to change just a bit of the code:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(yourMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Inside your void function you can make the verification to check if the code's running after 5 iterations:

```
- (void)myVoid{
    NSLog(@"Call Me");

    if (myInt == 5) {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }

    myInt++;
}
```

Comment: You can do it by passing the timer as function argument. No need to make the timer as member.

Comment: @Apurv: As Krishnabhadra had already shown this alternative, I tried to go other ways.